# Redemption : AddPSTSTORE not setting Display_name

Tags: python, python-2.7, outlook-redemption, outlook-2003

```
Store = SessionSrc.Stores.AddPSTStore(pst_path,1,'abc')
```

I am using this to add a pst file to attached pst's of Outlook.The problem is if i use the one below

```
Store = SessionSrc.Stores.AddPSTStore(pst_path,1)
```

It adds correctly with display_name of attached as `Personal Folders`.But when i provide a `display_name` to be set it doesnt use it and still add pst as `Personal Folders`.Is there a way to changes the `display_name` ?According to [redemption documents](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostores.htm)  , the 3rd optional argument is for setting `display_name`.Is it something different than what i am expecting?Do inform if more info is needed!!!

[image]

Comment: "Personal Folders"  is the PST provider display name. Outlook always uses the file name as display name in the folder tree view.

Comment: I don't think you can - Outlook would not let you change the display name of a ST store.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko but it does let us remove store by name......but it does not let rename it :(...........

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - what does it have to do with naming a PST store?

Comment: we can loop over stores and remove the one we want but we cant set the name.........isnt der any hack? You can add that as answer if you want :)

Comment: You can try to open the store and set the RDOStore.Name property.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko one last doubt....what does the 3rd argument of `Store = SessionSrc.Stores.AddPSTStore(pst_path,1,'abc')` does?

Comment: It is the store format - please see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostores.htm

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko the `'abc'` this argument....it said `display_name` something

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko the 3rd argument to `AddPSTStore` say for ex . `AddPSTStore(pst_path,1,'abc')` in this `abc`

Comment: It is the display name, which the PST provider sometimes takes, and sometimes ignores.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko thanx a lot for all the info and taking time out...you can add this as answer if you wish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PST provider sometimes ignores the specified displayed name when a PST store is added. Try to set the RDOStore.Name property after the store is added.